# Android WebView Responsive Youtube not playing

Tags: android, android-webview, android-youtube-api

I have a very basic WebActivity that serves up a page that has the styling of

```
CSS

.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

Next, edit add some HTML around your embed code.
HTML

<div class="video-container"><iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</iframe</div>
```

If I view this page with the browser on the device, the page loads and the video plays just fine.

However if I use a webview programmed into my app, and load the page,clicking on the like, I get a message on the youtube video window (after the loading spinner) of "An error occurred.  Please try again later (Playback ID: xxxxxx) Learn More"

of which learn more does not display anything useful.  Idea's on how to go about seeing what is going on?  The Android Studio logcat is not displaying any issues?
[image: Image of playback error]

Comment: Anyone know of any debugging I can try in order to get why the YouTube JS is reporting "An error occurred" ?

Comment: How do you load the iframe? In a HTML file?

Comment: yes from HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it turns out that there are a few more params needed to play embeded iframe videos from YouTube.

Had to add the following to the end of the url string

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxx?version=3&enablejsapi=1"

Answer (score 0):

I have create a demo for it. You may visit my github [link](https://github.com/Barai-Vivek/YoutubeWithResponsiveIFrame)